# I'm unable to restart apache2

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, server, apache2

I updated my packages for my VM Instance in Google Cloud.
Since then I'm unable to access my web panel and all the websites in it

```
help@hcp:~$ systemctl status apache2.service
× apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-03-25 22:02:29 UTC; 1min 51s ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 17976 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 21ms

Mar 25 22:02:29 hcp.newwton.in systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAIL>
Mar 25 22:02:29 hcp.newwton.in systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 25 22:02:29 hcp.newwton.in apachectl[17979]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's f>
Mar 25 22:02:29 hcp.newwton.in apachectl[17979]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bin>
Mar 25 22:02:29 hcp.newwton.in apachectl[17979]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bin>
Mar 25 22:02:29 hcp.newwton.in apachectl[17979]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Mar 25 22:02:29 hcp.newwton.in apachectl[17979]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Mar 25 22:02:29 hcp.newwton.in systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Mar 25 22:02:29 hcp.newwton.in apachectl[17976]: Action 'start' failed.
Mar 25 22:02:29 hcp.newwton.in apachectl[17976]: The Apache error log may have more information.
lines 1-17/17 (END)
```

I tried to delete apache2 and reinstall again.

// More details

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1030-gcp x86_64)


  System load:  0.0732421875       Processes:             131
  Usage of /:   44.3% of 28.89GB   Users logged in:       1
  Memory usage: 37%                IPv4 address for ens4: 10.128.0.2
  Swap usage:   6%
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message `Address already in use` indicates the problem.

The TCP port number that Apache wants to bind to (listen for connections) is already in use by another process. That can be caused by having another server running or a crashed Apache process.

If there is another server running, you will either need to stop that server or select a different port number. To determine which processes are listening to which ports run this command:

`netstat -ltnp`

Some systems do not have `netstat` installed. To install run this command:

`sudo apt-get install net-tools`

If the problem is a crashed Apache process, try rebooting the server. If Apache crashes after restarting, you will need to review the Apache log files for more details.